# How can I make my text appear below the navbar?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm currently coding my first website and I'm experiencing a problem I don't know how to solve. I have a home page with a navbar, and when I put text in the page, it appears cut because the text starts behind the navbar. How can I make the text appear below the navbar?

Here's the code.

```css
body {
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-color: rosybrown;
}
```

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
   <meta charset= "UTF-8"> 
   <title>DNA TRANSLATOR</title>
    <meta charset= "UTF-8"/> 
    <meta name= "viewport" 
   content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href= '{% static
   "css/style.css" %}'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style='background-color: snow;'>
      <div class = 'container'>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DNA Translator</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Translator</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Process</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class = "container">
        {% block content%}

        {% endblock content%}
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need basicly to add a padding-top to your main container that is equal to nav height.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably duplicate question. But I answer it anyway.

Basicly when you set nav as `position: fixed;` You must add a padding-top or margin-top to your main container or body to start from the very bottom of the navbar.

So basicly I added padding-top to body (recommanded practice):

```
body{
      padding-top: 56px;
    }
```

OR  `margin-top` or `padding-top` to `.main.container`

```
.main.container{
          margin-top: 56px;
        }
```

```css
body {
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-color: rosybrown;
   padding-top: 56px;
}
```

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
   <meta charset= "UTF-8"> 
   <title>DNA TRANSLATOR</title>
    <meta charset= "UTF-8"/> 
    <meta name= "viewport" 
   content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href= '{% static
   "css/style.css" %}'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style='background-color: snow;'>
      <div class = 'container'>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DNA Translator</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Translator</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Process</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class = "main container">
        {% block content%}

        {% endblock content%}
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus id nulla eu imperdiet. Fusce imperdiet tellus eu sem hendrerit, eu consequat leo rhoncus. Nullam vehicula nunc id leo consequat, et bibendum magna fringilla. Proin rhoncus aliquam odio, sed euismod lectus efficitur ut. Nam faucibus nisi ullamcorper, luctus quam id, rutrum nisi. Sed ac interdum ante, ultrices aliquam eros. Nulla arcu urna, lacinia eu accumsan sed, consectetur et dui. Vivamus mi nisl, dapibus vel justo vitae, dignissim ornare nisl. Maecenas condimentum ex id erat consequat porttitor. Duis auctor sed nisl at blandit. Phasellus maximus purus vel efficitur consequat. Donec tempus justo in metus pellentesque dignissim. Nulla facilisi. Aenean vulputate dictum turpis id mattis. Integer turpis metus, fermentum eget blandit elementum, ultrices hendrerit arcu.
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text is behind the navbar because you gave it a fixed position with the "fixed-top" class. If you dont want to have a fixed navbar, i think you can just remove that classname.

If you want to have a fixed navbar, you can move your container down with css, use "margin-top" for that with the height of your navbar and your content will be visible right under the navbar.